# How to change the url of a g:image in gwt

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm new to GWT.
I created in my ui.xml a panel containing an Image.
I want to change the url, the alt & the title of that image depending some conditions. How to do it ?

```
<g:Image url="images/document-statut-1.gif" title="My title" altText="My alt"></g:Image>
```

Thnx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify the uibinder element so it has a field name:

```
<g:Image url="images/document-statut-1.gif" ui:field="imageWidget"
         title="My title" altText="My alt" />
```

Then make a matching field in your java code:

```
@UiField
Image imageWidget;
```

Any time after you call the `createAndBind` method in your java class, you can then assign a new url:

```
imageWidget.setUrl("images/newStatus.gif");
```

Comment: It's working, and this is what I did, I forgot answering it :p Thnx.