# How to dynamically change the image specified in UI markup?

Tags: uibinder, gwt2

For UI markup, I use UIBinder. In a specific area, I want to place the logo and then dynamically change it:

```
<ui:UiBinder 
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' 
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' >
<ui:with 
    field='res' 
    type='com.myproject.client.resources.Resources' />

<g:Image resource='{res.offline}'/>
```

ClientBundle:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {    
    @Source("offline.png")  
    public ImageResource offline();

    @Source("online.png")  
    public ImageResource online();

    // ... and so on 
}
```

When a user starts a session, his logo changes.

How to change the image that declared in the UI markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may be as follows.

Add the `UI:field` attribute in the markup:

`<g:Image  url='{res.user1.getURL}' ui:field="imageUser1" />`

Then, change the attribute value by this way:

```
@UiField Image imageUser1;
imageUser1.setVisible(true/ false);
```

It is also possible dynamically change the image URL -

```
user1.setUrl(offlineImg.getUrl());
```

See also:

- [Path for images folder in GWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071517/path-for-images-folder-in-gwt-project)
- [Scaling an Image in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260458/scaling-an-image-in-gwt)
- [How to change the url of a g:image in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720758/how-to-change-the-url-of-a-gimage-in-gwt)